# How to read SPSS aka (.sav) in Python

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, metadata, spss

It's my first time using Jupyter Notebook to analyze survey data (.sav file), and I would like to read it in a way it will show the metadata so I can connect the answers with the questions. I'm totally a newbie in this field, so any help is appreciated!

```
import pandas as pd
import pyreadstat
df, meta = pyreadstat.read_sav('./SimData/survey_1.sav')
type(df)
type(meta)
df.head()
```

Please lmk if there is an additional step needed for me to be able to see the metadata!

Answer (score 9):

The meta object contains the metadata you are looking for. Probably the most useful attributes to look at are:

- meta.column_names_to_labels : it's a dictionary with column names as you have in your pandas dataframe to labels meaning longer explanations on the meaning of each column

```
print(meta.column_names_to_labels)
```

- meta.variable_value_labels : a dict where keys are column names and values are a dict where the keys are values you find in your dataframe and values are value labels.

```
print(meta.variable_value_labels)
```

For instance if you have a column "gender' with values 1 and 2, you could get:
{"gender": {1:"male", 2:"female"}}
which means value 1 is male and 2 female.
You can get those labels from the beginning if you pass the argument apply_value_formats :

```
df, meta = pyreadstat.read_sav('survey.sav', apply_value_formats=True)
```

You can also apply those value formats to your dataframe anytime with pyreadstat.set_value_labels which returns a copy of your dataframe with labels:

```
df_copy = pyreadstat.set_value_labels(df, meta)
```

- meta.missing_ranges : you get labels for missing values. Let's say in the survey in certain variable they encoded 1 meaning yes, 2 no and then mussing values, 5 meaning didn't answer, 6 person not at home. When you read the dataframe by default you will get values 1 and 2 and NaN (missing) instead of 5 and 6. You can pass the argument user_missing to get 5 and 6, and meta.missing_ranges will tell you that 5 and 6 are missing values. Variable_value_labels will give you the "didn't answer" and "person not at home" labels.

```
df, meta = pyreadstat.read_sav("survey.sav", user_missing=True)
print(meta.missing_ranges)
print(meta.variable_value_labels)
```

These are the potential pieces of information useful for your case, not necessarily all of these pieces will be present in your dataset.

More information here: https://ofajardo.github.io/pyreadstat_documentation/_build/html/index.html